# Laravel 5: Pagination and Xampp: Object not found

Tags: php, laravel, mod-rewrite, laravel-5, xampp

I am doing simple pagination on a query.

The pagination links at the bottom of the page are pointing to

`http://localhost/reddit/public/subreddit/?page=1`

but when I click on it, I get redirected to

`http://localhost/subreddit?page=1`

with the error

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error:
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost
>
> Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.11

But if I manually go to `http://localhost/reddit/public/subreddit?page=2` the page loads fine.

This is the `url` in `config/app.php`

```
'url' => 'http://localhost/reddit/public',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your url is set to `http://localhost/reddit/public`, Laravel will generate relative links based on the url configuration.
In other words, it's taking out http://localhost/reddit/public from all the links, and only adding `subreddit?page=1`

Setting the `url` field in `config/app.php` back to `'url' => 'http://localhost/',` should fix the problem

Comment: That didn't change anything, still getting the same error and same links.

Comment: alternatively, try adding this after `paginate()`:
`$replace_me->setPath('custom/url');`

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Is this a problem with xampp or laravel? Do I have to do this everytime I use paginate() ?

Comment: This is a temporary fix, i'm trying to find a more in-depth solution

Comment: Will we face the same problem on a live server?

Comment: Seems like this is the best method that I can think of for now.
`setPath` takes your root folder into account, so it should work fine. If you can't fix the problem if it happens on your production server, let me know in the comments here and I'll help you out.